# support ie8 Asynchronous file upload error

Tags: html, ajax, file, iframe, upload

Customor wanna File upload which support ie8. So I decide to use iframe to send file like ajax.

```
<iframe name="dummy" id="dummy" src="" height="0" width="0"></iframe>

                                    <form id="frmfile" name="frmfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        <input type="text" id="FILEA" class="y_input" size="103" disabled="disabled">
                                        <input type="hidden" id="FILE_ID" name="FILE_ID"><input type="file" id="FILEDATAA" name="FILEDATAA">
                                </form>



                    var frm = document.getElementById("frmfile");
                frm.action = "/fileUpload.do";
                frm.target = "dummy";
                //frm.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
                frm.method = "POST";

                jQuery("#dummy").off("load");
                jQuery("#dummy").on("load", function() {
                    var res = jQuery(this).contents().find('body').html().toString();
                    alert("aa"+res);
                    var vData = JSON.parse(res);
                    if(vData != null && vData != ""){
                        alert("file uploaded");
}else{
alert("error");
}
                 vData = null;
                 res = null;
                });
                frm.submit();
```

currently I'm using same domain.
ERROR

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "DOMAIN" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

error is start here "jQuery(this).contents().find('body').html().toString();"

File is succesfully uploaded every single try.
but the thing is when I tyring to get callback data it get's error.

I tried put document.domain = 'domain';
but nothing changed..

server return data like this.

```
{Data: [{fileSeq: 1, fileid: "6574"}]}
```

Comment: You need to set document.domain to the same value on both the parent window and the iframe

Comment: Can you show me a example? @sideshowbarker

Comment: An generic example wouldn’t do you any good. What value to set document.domain depends on the actual domain names of the parent window and iframe. So what you should do is, use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43405623/edit to edit/update your question to add information about the domain names

Comment: Domain is private so even if I tell you you never could connect.  
I tried iframe,actual jsp document.name but It still didn't work... @sideshowbarker

Comment: Yeah I don’t want to connect to you. But anyway if the parent is foo.example.com and the iframe is bar.example.com, then you need to set document.domain to *example.com* for both

Comment: parent is sales.foo.com, iframe src ""(empty) iframe is just using for send file(post). so it's diffrent should I setting it?
but iframe has no src.. so I can't setting document.domain